# Flag count discrepancy in moderator history

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, moderation-history

In the moderator history there is a global flag count as well as a per-mod list of handled flags. I would expect the total flag count in the top left to be the sum of all the per-moderator flag counts. This is not the case, the per-mod flags add up to only about half of the total flag count.

If I switch to the daily view I even get a total of 4 flags displayed in the top left, although every mod has a zero flag count in the table.

Am I misunderstanding the flag counts displayed on that page or is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: Does your table show every SE employee? They can handle flags anywhere AFAICT.

Comment: @John, if an SE employee handled a flag he is visible in that list. This is the overview for today, and today no SE employee handled a flag on Skeptics, so you don't see them.

Comment: Ah ok. I'm not a mod anywhere so just checking.

Comment: +1 the total and individual scores for today don't match up on SU either, and the few pending aren't sufficient to account for the discrepancy.

Comment: Could it be that there were self-resolving flags? I.e. flags on a question where the community closed the post before a moderator had a chance to look?

Comment: Small update to my answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll check the queries, but please note that ***the community*** is also capable of dismissing flags, by hammering a post into submission. Indeed, flags on posts that are self-deleted are generally dismissed too. Meaning: it is entirely possible that the remainder are either the OP deleting a post that raised a lot of flags, or the community flagging it enough times (spam or offensive) such that it was deleted automatically.

Edit: the total number is the number *created*, not those that were specifically handled by moderators. Anything flagged but subsequently removed by either the *poster*, or mob-rule, will not be reflected in the numbers on the right.

---

Additional; the above was incomplete (although the two reasons provided *are* valid reasons for differences). It turns out that the 4 votes on skeptics.SE are due to comments. Comments are given a very light touch, and are not currently *formally* tied to the moderator who marks them as completed, however I *can* reveal that 4 comments were deleted by Fabian (your good self) today between 07:50 and 07:51 UTC today. So "comments" was the explanation in this case.

I think querying this could be bit expensive for the main table; however, I suspect we could display this on the "more detail...", so *next time*, clicking into a few users should reveal all. I believe we already display comment *edits* by moderators - it is just a cased of adding comment deletes.

---

Changes that have been made as a result of this meta question:

- the "Cmnts Deleted" column was... *specious* (ok, just plain wrong) - it is fixed
- there is now greater visibility of comment deletes on a post's moderation history
- there is now greater visibility of comment deletes on a moderators (recent) history

Comment: Thanks for checking, that is one possibility I didn't consider, but I'm pretty sure that Skeptics didn't have 4 community-resolved flags today and the tools don't show any deleted posts in that time. I suspect that this is only part of the explanation.

Comment: I've noticed that on Programmers, I dealt with something like 10 flags the other day but the count only increased by (I think) 3. Sorry about the hand-waving here, I'm not sure what the discrepancy was but it was there. What counts as "handling" a flag for a moderator?

Comment: Okay, I think I know now what the missing flags are, those were for comments I deleted by flagging earlier this day, which don't appear to be considered handled by me. I thought the overview didn't count comment flags at all.

Comment: @Fabian I'm double checking those as I type, as it happens