# Mod Flag History: 2+2=50

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, statistics, caching

I'd like to blame caching, but I can't shake the feeling that something's flaky here:

[image: 48+27+21+14+13=200]

That's a bug, right? No matter which tab I'm looking at (day|week|month|whatever), nothing ever seems to add up.

Can it be fixed?

Comment: You should have given the quarterly stats as the example. My stats are better on the quarter stats :)

Comment: Are there any flags handled by SE amployees?

Comment: Multiple flags on one post are added multiple times to the number at the top, but it's only one flag handled for the handling moderator. Also, maybe NAA and VLQ flags that are handled in the review queue may be counted at the top. (We have 1k [1041] at the top vs. 278 moderator-handlings this week in our stats.)

Comment: @terdon not in that tab, no.

Comment: @terdon Not in the weekly or daily stats, no. And even if those would be included for the relevant tabs, it still doesn't add up.

Comment: Those counters count different things, which isn't obvious from the dashboar+d. Not all flags are included in both counters, though I don't remember exactly what the differences are. [See this old bug report of mine for some more information](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106659/151385)

Comment: @DanielFischer that might be wort an answer. Sounds like it could be the issue.

Comment: @DanielFischer Seems like a house is not a home, and a flag is not a flag...

Comment: While we're at it, could we change that orange to something actually readable? I use a userscript developed by another mod for this but it should be fixed.

Comment: As near as I have been able to tell, the per-user number is the number of distinct posts, the total is all flags.

Comment: Well, regardless of what it is, UX-wise, the fact that flags have that orange background, and the total also has the same orange background, looks very very much like it's intended to be showing the sum of the figures. How about we have it say "X flags on Y posts" instead?

Comment: This is true for sufficiently large values of 2. ;)

Comment: Someone was going to make [2+2=5](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28786/write-a-program-that-makes-2-2-5), but accidentally added a zero.

Comment: @SimonForsberg: I would've preferred the all-time stats myself. ;-)

Answer (score 13):

I reported this issue around 4 years ago (see [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106658/151385)), and while some bugs related to this were fixed, the flag counter at the top still counts different things than the per-mod flag counters. This is certainly confusing, but I'm not entirely sure if it is by design or not.

There are two big categories that are counted in the top counter that the per-mod counters don't count:

- flags resolved by the community
- comment flags

Maybe those should just be broken out and displayed separately, and not just in the one big flag counter to rule them all. There is really no way to actually figure out what this thing is counting except for asking an SE developer, and that can be rather confusing.

Comment: Comment flags are counted in the per-mod stats. The problem is the per-mod stat is calculated per-post. So if you handle two, five, or twelve flags on a single post at once, it still only counts one in your stats. So it can seem like comment flags don't count, since those more frequently come in waves on a post.